# Reshaping / Transforming pandas.Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, reshape

Hej there,

I've got the following pandas.DataFrame

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({
  "date": ["2016-12-11", "2016-12-12", "2016-12-13", "2016-12-14", "2016-12-15"], 
  "dim1": ["dim11", "dim12", "dim12", "dim11", "dim13"],
  "dim2": ["dim22", "dim21", "dim21", "dim22", "dim23"],
  "dim3": ["dim31", "dim32", "dim32", "dim31", "dim33"],
  "val1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  "val2": [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  "val3": [11,12,13,14,15]
  })
```

What I want now is to specify multiple "dimensions" and multiple "values", so that the DataFrame
is reshaped / transformed so that the specified dimensions and values are "combined" with each other.
Not specified values may vanish but specified dimensions should stay in the resulting DataFrame.

To make it clear a simple example of a resulting DataFrame.
Specified dimensions are: dim1, dim2
Specified values are: val1, val2

```
df_res = pandas.DataFrame({
  "date": ["2016-12-11", "2016-12-12", "2016-12-13", "2016-12-14", "2016-12-15"],
  "dim3": ["dim31", "dim32", "dim32", "dim31", "dim33"],
  "dim11_dim22_val1": [1, 0, 0, 4, 0],
  "dim12_dim21_val1": [0, 2, 3, 0, 0],
  "dim13_dim23_val1": [0, 0, 0, 0, 5],
  "dim11_dim22_val2": [6, 0, 0, 9, 0],
  "dim12_dim21_val2": [0, 7, 8, 0, 0],
  "dim13_dim23_val2": [0, 0, 0, 0, 10]
})
```

So basically there are multiple combinations of dim1, dim2, val1 and val2. val3 drops from the result but the dimensions date_id and dim3 stay in there.

As a side note: Afterwards I will do a df_res.to_dict(orient="records"), which should output

```
[
  {"date_id": "2016-12-11", "dim3": "dim31", "dim11_dim22_val1": 1, "dim12_dim21_val1": 0, "dim13_dim23_val1": 0, "dim11_dim22_val2": 6, "dim12_dim21_val2": 0, "dim13_dim23_val2": 0}
  ...
]
```

Can I do this with some pandas magic? 
Maybe in multiple steps of df.pivot?

Kind regards
Dennis

Comment: Two questions is too much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Part 1:***

1) You could set the columns starting with *dim* along with *date* which would remain static during the whole operation as the index axis. Provide `append=True` to confront duplicated indices.

2) `unstack` the required levels. Drop the unwanted `val3` column and fill missing values with 0's.

3) Rename the columns by joining the multi-index tuples with an underscore in between them.

4) Reset the same levels as unstacked and additionally sort the column names to match the required output.

---

```
df.set_index(df.filter(like='dim').columns.tolist()+['date'], append=True, inplace=True)
df = df.unstack(level=[2,1]).drop('val3', axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int)
df.columns = ['_'.join(c[::-1]) for c in df.columns]
df_res = df.reset_index(level=[2,1]).sort_index(axis=1)
df_res
```

[image]

---

***Part 2:***

```
df_res.to_dict('r')
```

produces:

```
[{'date': '2016-12-11',
  'dim11_dim22_val1': 1,
  'dim11_dim22_val2': 6,
  'dim12_dim21_val1': 0,
  'dim12_dim21_val2': 0,
  'dim13_dim23_val1': 0,
  'dim13_dim23_val2': 0,
  'dim3': 'dim31'}, ..........
```

Comment: That helped a lot. Thank you!